# Recursion in sql with loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a table,

where there are users and each of them has supervisior. However the CEO does not have a supervisior and he is supervisior of himself. (i.e, supervisiorid of CEO is UserId of CEO)

I have a requirement to find list of all subordinates under a given userid. I am using below query.

```
WITH CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY AS
(
    SELECT E.UserId, E.SupervisiorId AS Supervisor, d.DepartmentName,d.DepartmentId
    FROM T_BIT_Users  E with (nolock) inner join T_BIT_Department d with (nolock) on d.DepartmentId=e.DepartmentId  WHERE E.UserId = 13

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E1.UserId,  E1.SupervisiorId  AS Supervisor,d.DepartmentName,d.DepartmentId
    FROM CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY  
    JOIN T_BIT_Users E1 
    ON E1.SupervisiorId = CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY.UserId
       inner join T_BIT_Department d on d.DepartmentId=e1.DepartmentId)
SELECT  * FROM CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY
OPTION  ( MAXRECURSION 0 )
```

this keeps on going in loop forever.

Any suggestions.?

Comment: How about creating http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d4a6/1  I tried, making it. however i dont know exact syntax in mysql

Comment: @AmitKumar for future reference sqlfiddle allows you to change the RDMS up in the top left, ie, you could have made your sqlfiddle use mssql server

Comment: Will take a note of that. thank u Jamiec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just limit the recursive part to exclude where `supervisorId = userId`

```
SELECT E1.UserId,  E1.SupervisiorId  AS Supervisor,d.DepartmentName,d.DepartmentId
FROM CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY  
JOIN T_BIT_Users E1 
ON E1.SupervisiorId = CTE_EMPLOYEE_HEIRARCHY.UserId
   inner join T_BIT_Department d on d.DepartmentId=e1.DepartmentId
WHERE E1.SupervisorId != E1.UserId # <-- here
```

Comment: I Need the supervisor(passed userId) too.

Comment: @AmitKumar thats in the first part of the CTE query though, right?  `WHERE E.UserId = 13` <-- I assumed this part was where you were passing in an ID

Comment: Yes, there i am passing userId